# Error using flexibility polyfil

Tags: javascript, polyfills, flexibility

I'm trying to use [this polyfill](https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility) to allow me use flexbox in IE8 and 9, but I'm just getting errors.

I have version 1.0.6 included in my project, as the [latest version doesn't work according to the issues](https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility/issues/78#issuecomment-246647790).

I am then calling it using the following code in my site.js file:

```
function supportsFlexBox() {
    var test = document.createElement('test');

    test.style.display = 'flex';

    return test.style.display === 'flex';
}

if (supportsFlexBox()) {
    // Modern Flexbox is supported
} else {
    flexibility(document.documentElement);
}
```

However, I am getting the following error in console on IE9:

```
Function expected
```

I have also tried using just the following code (without the wrapping if statement):

```
flexibility(document.documentElement);
```

But I get the following error in Chrome

```
flexibility is not a function
```

Has anyone used this polyfill and it working before, or able to help me get this working? I'm not sure if im calling the function incorrectly or if there is a bug in the polyfill itself.

Comment: Does it happen if you wrap your code in `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {…})`? I suspect you might be calling `flexibility` before it actually loads.

Comment: Unfortunately that still gives the same error

Comment: Yeah, sorry, just tried it on Codepen and it doesn't help. Version 2.0.1 loads without errors, but it's broken in another ways… And the upstream seems to be abandoned.

Comment: Ah well, guess I'll have to just use css to fix any flex issues until there's a working polyfill available. Thanks for you help